# String [][] clarification

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm just asking about this instruction:

```
String[][] s = new String[2][2];
```

If i create this variable "s", will i create a string table with 2 lines and 2 columns ?
Or 2 tables with 2 elements? 
Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: I changed the tag from android to java. This is a java issue, not an android specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has no build-in *table* datatype, the only native basic types of types (metatypes?) are

- primitive values (numerics, char and boolean)
- arrays (linear indexable collections of variables of the same type).
- objects of classes (basically a collection of named variables of specified type, together with some methods, fixed by class). (Strings are examples of this.)

Everything else must be composed of those types. (To complicate this, the array types are all considered subtypes of `java.lang.Object`, which is the class from which all other classes inherit.)

So you can have arrays of a specific class, classes which have array-types as class variables (fields), and also arrays of arrays, as here.

Your `String[][]` type consists of arrays of arrays of String, and the `new String[2][2]` array creation expression creates an array of length two, each element being itself an array of length two. Each element of these arrays can be a string, but on creation it is first `null`.

```
 s --> [ 0 ,  1 ]
         |    '----> [ null, null ]
         |
         '---------> [ null, null ]
```

You now can put in the places of these `null`s references to actual `String` objects, if you want, by using `s[0][1] = "Hello";` and similar statements.

As said already by the other answerers, such a 2D-array can be viewed as a table with rows and columns, if you want, but it is nothing special from the language viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

It creates a two-dimensional array with an array of two elements in both dimensions.

Depending on the sole purpose of the variable and the data it actually holds, you're free to interpret the whole whatever way you want. A table (a matrix) with 2 columns and 2 rows is perfectly fine.

Comment: please see my second comment.

Comment: so why simply use a table! what's the main purpose of using 2D arrays?

Comment: The purpose is to be able to reference specific data using two variables. A graph for example. First variable is then the x axis and second the y axis. Or just a table with rows/columns of course (a better word is a matrix or grid).

Comment: @androniennn - Why do you keep saying "table". This isn't a database, it's programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are hung up about which is the *one true explanation*.

In reality, they are are many correct explanations or conceptual models.  Which of these is most appropriate / makes the most sense *depends on the conceptual level* your are thinking at.

- At the level of the language / JVM specification you have an array of arrays of strings.
- At the syntactic level you have something that looks like a 2-D array of strings, with columns and rows.  For a lot of operations it will behave exactly like a 2-D array.

  (You can do things to make your String[][] not behave like a conventional 2-D array.  For example, you can replace a row to give an "array" in which the rows have different lengths.  But that only happens if you "assign" a whole row.)
- At the application level what you have can be thought of as a table ... if you want to.

The explanation that you linked to in one of your comments is correct, and so are all of the answers.  They are all saying (or trying to say) the same thing.

(BTW - this is what @BalusC's answer is saying.  I'm just elaborating.)

---

So when you ask:

> If i create this variable "s", will i create a string table with 2 lines and 2 columns ? Or 2 tables with 2 elements?

... the answer is that it is BOTH of those, depending on your perspective, and how your application uses them.  From other perspectives, it is also an array of arrays of strings, or a 2-D array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a two dimensional array.  This is an array of arrays.

Comment: array of arrays ? so finally we will have an array of 4 columns and 4 lines with s[2][2]! 2 arrays included in 2 arrays!

Answer (score 1):

This will technically create an array - of length 2 - of string arrays - also of length 2.

But for all practical purposes it can be thought of as creating a table with 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: what do you mean by "of length 2"? 2 rows and 2 columns ? and why not simply using tables ? what'is the major difference ?

Comment: The thing is, that in java there is no built in structure called a table. All that exists are arrays. An array is what you can imagine as a table with just a single row, and the length of an array would be the number of columns it has.

Comment: the length of an array is the number of its lines i think! not its columns! no?

Comment: If you think of an array as a table with a single row, then the length of the array would be the number of columns. However if you think that a array as a table with a single column, then it's length is the number of rows.

Either way, when you create a 2D array, you are nesting rows inside columns or vice-versa to create a table with both rows and columns.

You're free to think of it whichever way you wish, so choose a method that suits your needs, but once you choose one, you should make sure you are consistent in using that interpretation throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no table.

There is an array, an array is simply a reference to the memory where the variables are actually stored.

it will actually create a matrix which is an array of which each element is an array... 
array one: [] []
array two: [] []

Comment: is it the right explanation: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2D array. just like writing

```
String [][] s = new  String[2][];
s[0] = new String[2];
s[1] = new String[2];
```

So I think both your options are correct.