# I'm not understanding the following code

Tags: android

I have to understand this code to create my own app(almost based on this function):

```
public static String[][] ReadFilePerLine(Context context, String nom) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(nom);
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            i = getLineNumber(context, nom);
            String[][] s = new String[2][i/2];
            i = 0;
            String ligne;
            int j = 0;
            while ((ligne = b.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    s[0][j] = ligne;
                else {
                    s[1][j] = ligne;
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            fIn.close();
            ipsr.close();
            return s;

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {}
```

I'm not understanding why the using of a 2D array? and with two rows ?(String[][] s = new String[2][i/2];)
here is the data that it will be stored in the file:

```
data = date + " : " + y + "L/100KM"+ " " + value1 + "L "+ value2 + "KM\n";
```

Necessary functions:

```
 public void updatelv(Activity activity) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
        fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
        s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir+fileName);
        ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        L.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, s[0]));
        for (int i = 0; i< s[0].length; i++) { 
            Log.d("Saves",s[0][i]); 
        } 
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.histo);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        activity = this;
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
        fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
        s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir + fileName);

        updatelv(this);
        ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        L.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        L.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                String tmp = s[1][position];
                if (tmp == null)
                    tmp = "Aucun fichier trouvé!";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tmp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
```

ReadFilePerLine function:

```
public static String[][] ReadFilePerLine(Context context, String nom) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(nom);
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            i = getLineNumber(context, nom);
            String[][] s = new String[2][i/2];
            i = 0;
            String ligne;
            int j = 0;
            while ((ligne = b.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    s[0][j] = ligne;
                else {
                    s[1][j] = ligne;
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            fIn.close();
            ipsr.close();
            return s;

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: I think it would help if you show the file's contents.

Comment: Please note that this function might cause ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception if the line number is odd - `String[][] s = new String[2][i/2];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [String \[\]\[\] clarification...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365884/string-clarification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what they are doing is breaking the file down into two lists (or String arrays, in this case), one which contains all the even-numbered lines, and one which contains all the odd-numbered lines.  I'll comment up the code for you:

```
public static String[][] ReadFilePerLine(Context context, String nom) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        //open the specified input file and create a reader
        FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(nom);
        InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(ipsr);

        //get the total number of lines in the file, and allocate 
        //a buffer large enough to hold them all
        i = getLineNumber(context, nom);
        String[][] s = new String[2][i/2];

        i = 0;      //set the current line to 0
        String ligne;
        int j = 0;  //set the section index to 0

        //now read through the lines in the file, and place every
        //even-numbered line in the first section ('s[0]'), and every 
        //odd-numbered line in the second section ('s[1]')
        while ((ligne = b.readLine()) != null) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                //even-numbered line, it goes into the first section
                s[0][j] = ligne;
            else {
                //odd-numbered line, it goes into the second section
                s[1][j] = ligne;
                j++;  //increment the section index
            }
            i++;  //increment the line count
        }

        //done, cleanup and return
        fIn.close();
        ipsr.close();
        return s;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //should at least log an error here...
    }
}
```

As to why they chose to use a String[][], I cannot say.  Probably for convenience, since they want a single object that they can return from this function that contains both lists.  Personally I would use a Map that has two List instances in it, but the String[][] works just as well and is probably marginally more efficient.

Judging from your example data it does not appear that you need to use this format.  But if you want to use it, you need to structure your data so that the key is on one line, and its associated value is on the next, like:

```
date
2011-03-19
userName
someGuy
```

Comment: @aroth: so to have the right diplay in the ListView with this format, i have to add a "\n" after every variable ? :\ !

Comment: Plus i don't know why he used a string [][] variable! he just had to use a string varible ! no ? plus the display is very difficul, for even and odd numbers(number of lines in the file!), useless, no ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to have a "\n" after every key and after every value.  And you're correct, a file with an odd number of lines will break this code, but if the file is correctly formatted it should not ever contain an odd number of lines.  Each variable being stored should have exactly two lines associated with it.  And of course, values that contain literal newlines in them will completely break this format, unless the newlines are manually escaped or otherwise sanitized.

Comment: @aroth:But i want to see all the variables in one line :\! in this case, a simple storing of a string variable is 100% useful and correct! no ? without the check of even and odd numbers !

Comment: @aroth: so can i modify the code to neglige the check if the number of line is even or odd and just diplay all the datas in the file ?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the code to do that.  But then why use the example code to begin with?  Regardless, if you change it to do `String[] s = new String[i];` and then replace the if/else inside the loop with `s[i] = ligne;` you will get a single list, with all of your data in it.

Comment: @aroth: so to conclude, the DEV just mades his program more difficult by using a 2D array, and checking for even and odd numbers ?

Comment: Yes and no.  If the original developer needed for some reason to parse an input file that had keys on one line and values on the next then this approach is not unreasonable (although better ways to accomplish the same thing certainly exist).  But if the file being parsed does not follow this format, then yes, the 2D array and line-number checks are not doing anything useful.

Comment: @aroth: Thank you aroth, i'll try to switch to a simple 1D string array, and i'll let you know if there is any news in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The code is clearly reading from a file whose format consists of pairs of lines; it puts the first line of each pair in `s[0][...]` and the second line of each pair in `s[1][...]`. If your format doesn't have that peculiarity -- which it doesn't sound as if it does -- then you don't need to do that. Just make an ordinary 1-dimensional array of `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to read from a file, split it into the two dimensional array (based on row count).

Why it does it? I have no idea why you'd want that. **Check out the function that it returns s to** and find out!

Comment: @andronienn if you look at the code it doesn't seem to reference s[1] at all... Maybe they've done it to discard half of the log.. OR, it's also being used elsewhere :/ For instance in that onCreate method, it does s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(..) and you've cut out the rest of that method..

Comment: @user551841: i edited the first post and added the rest of the code. I don't know why he's caring about even and odd number ! :\

Comment: Who knows why I didn't get any upvote for the same explanation

Comment: @user551841: sorry but i'm not understanding you :\ !